# Not all series have the same frequency for ts objects

Tags: r, time-series

I have the following from the package astsa in R.

```
data("cmort")  
data("tempr")  
data("part")   
t <- ts(1:length(cmort))
```

I am trying to plot the scatterplot matrix of these variables by using:

```
pairs(cbind(cmort, t, part))
```

But I got the error
 [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYU9m.png)

What is this error about? Whether all the variables are ts objects and have the same frequency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's exactly what is wrong. Look at the frequency of the three vectors:

```
> frequency(part)
[1] 52
> frequency(cmort)
[1] 52
> frequency(t)
[1] 1
```

The fix is to create a `t` vector that has the same frequency attribute.

```
t <- ts(1:length(cmort),frequency=52)
pairs(cbind(cmort,t,part))
```

Comment: Thanks for solving the problem.

Comment: Objects in R often have attributes. You can often see a listing of functions that access the attributes if you look at the help page for the function. That's how I deduced that I should use the `frequency` function to examine those objects. And then I saw that there was a `frequency<-` function (or the frequency parameter in the `ts` function). (I'm not a regular user of R's ts functions, but I do know my way around the help page system.)